# Explanation of the clause

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning, connotations

> "Here," I said, "deposit it." The tone of the words seemed to mean, "Let us do this painful thing **while the fit is on us**."

(Reference: MY FINANCIAL CAREER by Stephen Leacock)

What does the author actually want to imply in the dependent clause, while the fit is on us,? secondly, the text suggests that it is the author who is nervous while in this sentence he is using the pronoun 'us' as they both are nervous.

Comment: "While we're in the mood to make the resolution to do it".

Comment: What's the meaning of **on** in this sentence?

Answer (score 1):

One (rare) sense of "fit" is "a sudden burst of activity".  It is related to the medical sense of "uncontrolled movement caused (for example) by epilepsy".

So the sense here is "... while we are engaged in this burst of activity."  (and before we get "cold feet", and start to procrastinate)

The mood is rather poetic and elevated.

Comment: Here "on" mean "engaged in"?

Comment: No. The fit (the burst of activity) is **on** us.  TBH I don't see much point in talking about the meanings of individual prepostions in this context. YOu need to understand it at the level of the phrase.

Comment: I have not seen any usage of **on** as in this types of structure that's why i have  doubt..

Comment: Compare "when the spirit is on us"

Comment: N+v+pre+pronoun (I think this structure is rare), but **on** must have a meaning....

Comment: @Sam - consider it to be something like *to be happening to* : the fit is happening to us right now- the effects of the fit are influencing us.

Comment: Thank you, i got it , (could not get the meaning from dictionary )